# Query stuck on 0% ROLLBACK for 2 days

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, tempdb, rollback, wait-types

`kill with statusonly` returns:

> transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 0%.

The query creates a temp table and runs on local server without using xp_cmdshell.

- CPU & reads are not changing.
- Lock info: wait_type = LCK_M_SCH_M
- wait_resource = OBJECT: 2:-1211568747:21 meaning its waiting for a temp table in tempdb.

Server info:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: )

Is there any way to solve this without an instance restart?
Should I be expecting a database recovery?

`sp_whoisactive` shows its not blocked by anything. It's a temp in tempDB and its been 3 days now, I'm not sure something is going to happen.

Update:
I ran `beta_lockinfo` (documentation here: [beta_lockinfo](https://www.sommarskog.se/sqlutil/beta_lockinfo.html))
and it says the query is blocking itself, with the following info:

| blklvl | blkby | cnt | object | rsctype | locktype | lstatus | ownertype | rscsubtype | waittime | waittype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DD | 80 | 1 | #cdrtable | OBJECT | Sch-M | WAIT | TRANSACTION | [21] | 164116.577 | LCK_M_SCH_M |
| DD | 80 | 1 | DBName | DATABASE | S | grant | STW | [21] |  |  |
| DD | 80 | 1 | #cdrtable | OBJECT | Sch-M | grant | TRANSACTION | [21] |  |  |
| DD | 80 | 21 | #cdrtable | OBJECT | Sch-M | grant | TRANSACTION | [0-20] |  |  |
| DD | 80 | 1 | ProcName | OBJECT | Sch-M | grant | TRANSACTION | [21] |  |  |
| DD | 80 | 1 | sys.sysobjvalues | KEY | S | grant | TRANSACTION |  |  |  |
| DD | 80 | 1 | sys.sysobjvalues | OBJECT | Sch-S | grant | TRANSACTION | [21] |  |  |

Comment: Instance restart will not solve the issue as active transactions will be recommited or rollbacked again at start.

Comment: Could you create a test database and run the problematic query to see if it causes the same issue?

Comment: Yes I will recreate this on a local server and update

Comment: @Ronaldo I have tried reproducing but was unable. The query just stopped (after pressing stop button) and I couldnt even reach a state that I had to use KILL. But its a backup server and it was the only proccess. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been doing some research and I found references of self deadlocks that were bugs related to older versions like [kb2963138](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb2963138-fix-parallel-deadlock-or-self-deadlock-occurs-when-you-run-a-query-that-results-in-parallelism-in-sql-server-1c6b9301-9202-80cf-40d7-9626b3f4abec) and [KB4500574](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4500574-fix-self-deadlock-occurs-when-transaction-auditing-is-enabled-in-sql-server-2016-and-2017-740c2b9f-b401-0f92-571c-3e8d330b2240). Checking [Latest updates for Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/latest-updates-for-microsoft-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#latest-updates) it seems your instance is not patched to the latest CU (released Jun 14 2022).

Your attempt to reproduce the error was not successful, so your query might not have been the cause of the problem alone.

I understand you asked for a solution where no restart would be required (unfortunately none was provided) and on the comments it was said a restart could not solve the problem, but I think in this specific case a restart could solve your problem since you mention the lock occurs on `tempdb` and it's the only database that is discarded and recreated every time the instance reboots, as [the doc says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/tempdb-database?view=sql-server-ver16#overview):

> `tempdb` is re-created every time SQL Server is started so that the
> system always starts with a clean copy of the database.

Therefore, no [undo or redo phase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-and-recovery-overview-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#TlogAndRecovery) should happen to recreate your problem on the next boot of SQL Server.

I wouldn't recommend you to restart your instance based only on this assumption, but since you now have a real reason to restart your server (apply recent patches) I'm positive to recommend it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Eventually we did a restart and of course the query was gone. I am still very curious about how this happened and why. I should definitely patch the SQL server!