# spid locked in KILLED/ROLLBACK state

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SPID stuck in what appears to be a deadlock, in tempDB...

**sp_who2:**
[image]

**sp_lock:**

[image]

**KILL 81 WITH STATUSONLY:**

SPID 81: transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 0%. Estimated time remaining: 0 seconds.

Also, no other SPID has any locks on tempDB

MY QUESTION
Assuming that is enough info, how can I kill that SPID for good? It is stuck and not proceeding at all... this is on a non-prod data, I do not care about this transaction at all ...

Comment: What does `KILL 81 WITH STATUSONLY;` say?

Comment: @Ronaldo "SPID 81: transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 0%. Estimated time remaining: 0 seconds." 

been like this for 48 hours

Comment: It sounds like [this Q&A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314594/query-stuck-on-0-rollback-for-2-days) I tried to help a few days ago. Is your server patched?  Please, add the output of `SELECT @@version;` to the question.

Comment: Restart SQL Server? It's possiby caused by a leak in an ODBC provider

Comment: @Charlieface if I restart, is there a possibility that the server will start with tempDB in some recovery state and become unusable ?

Comment: Don't think so. `tempdb` is recreated anyway every time you start up